# Kendo UI gauge animation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gauge

I would like to animate my kendoUI gauges in realtime, whenever the data changes. I currently can do this by setting the values of the gauge pointer directly and refresh, but when i do that it will jump straight to the new value and not animate gracefully to it. How do I add the animation, like the Gauge control does when it first starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to refresh it, just set the new value using [`value`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/lineargauge#methods-value) and it gets updated and animated.

Example: Defined an HTML `input` that I decorate with a Kendo Numeric Text Box. Each time I update the value both a radial and linear gauge get updated.

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <input id="gauge-value" value="65">
</div>
<div id="gauge-container">
    <div id="gaugeR"></div>
    <div id="gaugeL"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (Gauges initialization):

```
var gaugeR = $("#gaugeR").kendoRadialGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: value.value()
    },
    scale  : {
        minorUnit : 5,
        startAngle: -30,
        endAngle  : 210,
        max       : 180
    }
}).data("kendoRadialGauge");

var gaugeL = $("#gaugeL").kendoLinearGauge({
    pointer: {
        value: value.value(),
        shape: "arrow"
    },
    scale  : {
        majorUnit: 20,
        minorUnit: 5,
        max      : 180
    }
}).data("kendoLinearGauge");
```

and `NumericTextBox` with change event handler that updates the `gauges`:

```
var value = $("#gauge-value").kendoNumericTextBox({
    min   : 0,
    max   : 180,
    change: function () {
        var v = $("#gauge-value").val();
        gaugeR.value(v);
        gaugeL.value(v);
    }
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

Example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vnGNj/)

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks OnaBai, I was updating the value incorrectly. If I could ask a followup question. What if I wanted to change the pointer color if it fell in a certain range without Redrawing the control?

Comment: Are we talking about radial or lineal gauge?

Comment: The only way that I know is invoking `redraw`. I don't know if this is what you mean by redrawing the control. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/vnGNj/2/ and try playing with different values.